# how to reading .raw file in c++

Tags: c++

```
    void solution3(){
        char str[100];
        int height, width;

        printf("가로와 세로 길이를 입력 : ");
        scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
        FILE* fp = fopen("lena_256x256.raw", "rb");

        //2dynimic
        unsigned char **p = new unsigned char*[height];

        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) *(p + i) = new unsigned char[width];
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                fread((void*)p[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), height * width, fp);
        }

        //print
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                printf("%4d ", p[i][j]);
        }

        //del dynimic
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i ++) delete[] p[i];
        delete[] p;

        fclose(fp);
    }

void main(){
 solution3();
}
```

Error message is "string != NULL" why cant read .raw file?
and I try `p[i][j]` fix `(void*)p[i][j]`. but can not.

I want read .raw and print info about .raw light

Comment: `void main` is not valid C++

Comment: There ary many issues. This question is too broad. You are lacking very basic knowledge.

Comment: You should check whether the call to `fopen` is successful - I suspect your input file is not in the current working directory, so you're getting "file not found".

Comment: haa.... sorry yeah I am lacking basic knowledge..

Comment: how can I reading .raw? I try search in google but cant solution

Answer (score 4):

The code has undefined behavior here:

> ```
>     unsigned char **p = new unsigned char*[height];
>     ....
>             fread((void*)p[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), height * width, fp);
> ```

`p` is a pointer to pointer of char. Which means that `p[i][j]` is a char, which the code casts to `(void*)`. This is an invalid address which `fread` tries to write to.

It is likely that you want:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        if (fread((void*)p[i], 1, width, fp) != width)
        {
           manage the error condition
        }
    }
```

Aside of that, it is not recommended to work directly with new/delete, and std::vector would be safer in this case. Also, `void main()` is wrong and should be `int main()` instead.